# Maximum number of cans within a box

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A box that is 4 ft. by 4 ft. by 4 ft. is packed with (cylindrical) cans that are 2 ft. high and have a diameter of 6 inches. When the box is fully packed with cans, how much space is wasted in the box?

My attempt at solving this:

You need to minimize this (I converted everything to feet):

$4^{3}\; -\; \pi \left( \frac{3}{12} \right)^{2}\left( 2 \right)\left( n \right)$

By equating to 0 and solving for n you get that n = $162.97$. Rounding down you get n = $162$. Now to find the wasted space simply plug in n into the above equation, and you get wasted space is $0.38274$ cubic feet.

However, the answer key to the problem says that the solution is 13.73 cubic feet. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It's impossible to say. How do you position the cans in the box? You could put then side-to-side and top-to-bottom so that each can meets every other can exactly once. The cans touch each other at 12 o'clock, 3 o'clock, 6 o'clock and 9 o'clock. Alternatively, they could be put together like pool balls where each row is off-set. These two set ups will give different distributions. You could even lie the cans down on their sides instead of standing them on their ends.

Comment: Consider if the box is 8ft x 6in x 6in.  Clearly it will fit 4 cans stacked atop each other.  Your equation, however, says I can fit 5.0929, rounding down to 5.  You're not taking fractional space into account properly.

Comment: Yes, but no matter the distribution, wouldn't the equation $4^{3}\; -\; \pi \left( \frac{3}{12} \right)^{2}\left( 2 \right)\left( n \right)$ assume the most efficient arrangement to minimize wasted space. Or are you saying that the solution key answer might have gone for a less efficient arrangement.

To the above person - might it fit 5 if the cans were laid sideways or other arrangements were used? The equation holds for the most efficient arrangement.

Comment: The cans are 2 feet tall and 6 inches in diameter.  The box is 8 feet tall and 6 inches square.  The cans are not going to fit "laid sideways" or any other way; You will never fit more than 4 cans into the box unless you cut the cans into pieces.  Your equation is basically assuming that you can cut a can into pieces to fit it into whatever odd spaces are available.

Comment: ohh... how should the equation be modified?

Comment: @Hellion The OP says that the box is $4\times 4 \times 4$.

Comment: @FlybyNight, I postulated a different-sized box to make the problem with his equation more readily apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the following is the equation of the wasted volume
$$
V= 4^3-2n\pi\left(\dfrac{3}{12}\right)^2 
\tag1
$$
where n is the number of cans in the box. You just need the number of cans. Each can can be held in a box with dimensions .5 ft x .5 ft x 2 ft. The maximum number of cans that can fit in the 4 ft x 4 ft x 4 ft box is equal to the number of these .5 x .5 x 2 ft boxes that can fit in the bigger box. Thus:
$$
n = \dfrac{4^3}{0.5^22}=128
$$
Thus the box can fit 128 cans. Plugging this number into Eq.(1) yields 13.73 ft$^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you put the cans in a systematic way (top to down, side to side manner):

Since the height of the cans is $2\text{ ft.}$, it is easy to see that only $2$ layers of cans will occupy the box vertically. Horizontally, you can place exactly $\dfrac{4\text{ ft}}{0.5 \text{ ft}}= 8$ cans (since the diametrical width of the cans is $0.5\text{ ft.})$ This also applies in the other direction. So you have a total of $2\cdot 8\cdot 8 = 128$ cans.

Volume of each can: $\pi \left( \frac{3}{12} \right)^{2} \cdot2 {\text{ ft}}^3$.

So volume wasted: $\left(4^3 - 128\cdot\pi \left( \frac{3}{12} \right)^{2} \cdot2 \right){\text{ ft}}^3 \approx 13.73 {\text{ ft.}}^3$